# cmake in cygwin: cyglto_plugin.dll not found

Tags: cygwin, gfortran

I am trying to get a Fortran 90 program to compile under Windows. I have already successfully done so under Linux.

I am using the 'Babun' windows shell, which is basically a wrapper for cygwin: https://github.com/babun/babun

When I try and run cmake, I get the following:

```
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran.exe
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran.exe  -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8.9/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:40 (MESSAGE):
  The Fortran compiler "/usr/bin/gfortran.exe" is not able to compile a
  simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /cygdrive/d/Users/bob/code/vasa/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make.exe "cmTryCompileExec674739544/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec674739544.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec674739544.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/cygdrive/d/Users/bob/code/vasa/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report
  /cygdrive/d/Users/bob/code/vasa/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
  1

  Building Fortran object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec674739544.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.o

  /usr/bin/gfortran.exe -c
  /cygdrive/d/Users/bob/code/vasa/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testFortranCompiler.f
  -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec674739544.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.o

  Linking Fortran executable cmTryCompileExec674739544.exe

  /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec674739544.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

  /usr/bin/gfortran.exe -Wl,--enable-auto-import
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec674739544.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.o -o
  cmTryCompileExec674739544.exe
  -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTryCompileExec674739544.dll.a
  -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0

  gfortran: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found

  compilation terminated.

  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec674739544.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target
  'cmTryCompileExec674739544.exe' failed

  make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec674739544.exe] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/cygdrive/d/Users/bob/code/vasa/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec674739544/fast' failed

  make: *** [cmTryCompileExec674739544/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (enable_language)
```

What package does this `cyglto_plugin.dll` belong to? What dependencies am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It's part of `gcc-core`, which I would expect you to have, as gfortran should be dependent upon it. You should be able to find it in `usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/<gcc-version>` if on Cygwin-32 or in `usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/<gcc-version>` on Cygwin-64.

Comment: I had installed gcc-core, but the dll is nowhere to be found. I uninstalled babun and went back to cygwin, all works fine now, so I guess this is an issue in the babun package manager. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like babun installs Cygwin as part of itself. That's a really bad thing to do. You likely ended up with two installations of Cygwin. The babun one probably didn't have all the pieces you needed. I'm guessing you were supposed to use it's "pact" tool to get them.

Comment: I removed cygwin before installing babun, then used pact to install gcc, cmake and so on, but the combination of confusing paths and lack of documentation meant I couldn't figure out the missing dependencies. Fundamentally the missing dll was not to be found in the cygwin path, despite gcc-core being installed.

Comment: I just downloaded this and attempted it. pact installs gfortran 4.8.3, but the gcc version installed is 4.8.2. cyglto_plugin.dll is in the 4.8.2 dir, where gfortran isn't looking for it. I moved everything from the 4.8.3 dir into the 4.8.2 (it was just Fortran stuff, so no overlaps), removed the 4.8.3 dir and created a symbolic link from 4.8.2 to 4.8.3. Then your -fuse-linker-plugin switch works. Of course doing something like this is fraught with peril, and will probably bite me later if I continue to use it.

Comment: Thanks Chris - if you want to add that as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted one?